# How to extract fasta sequences in a file which header line matches with list in another file?

Tags: regex, perl, extract, fasta

I'm a newbie to Perl. I am trying to extract the fasta sequences from one file which matches with lines in another file. The two example files are as follows:

File1.fasta:

> >gene_44|105_nt|+|47540|47644
>   GTGCGCCGGCGCGTCGCGATCGCGAACCGGCCCGTGCGAATCCTGCCGCATGCGCGCCGCATCTCGCCACGCCGCGCATTTCATTTCGACATCCATAACGTCTGA
>
> >gene_69|111_nt|+|75846|75956
>   ATGCCGTTGCCGTCGCGCATCGCGGCGGCCGTGCGCGGCGCGCATGCATACGCCGGCACGGCCGATGCGCGCGCGACGCGCAAACTGCACGCGGCGCGGGATTTGTGTTGA
>
> >gene_88|177_nt|-|97993|98169
>   ATGCGCCAGCCGACGCACGCCCATTCCGGGCGAAACGTTCCCCTTATCCATTCGATCATCCGTGCCGCACTGCGCGAAGCGGCCACCGCCGACACGTACCAAACCGCGCTCGATGCGACCGGCGCGGCACTCGTCGCCATCGCGGCGCTCGTGCGCGCGGAGGTGCGGCATGGCTGA
>
> >gene_90|141_nt|-|99016|99156
>   TTGGAAGGGCGCTTTCCGCGTGCGAGTCGTCTGACGCAGCGTTGCACGGTCTGGTCGAATCGCGAGCTTCATCGCTGGATGGCCGATCCGTTGAACTATCGCGCTGTCGACGCGGCGAACCAGACGACGGAGGGCGCGTAA

File2.list:

> somewordsinfront, >gene_44|somewordsattheback
>
> blablabla, >gene_88|blablablablabla

The output that I expect is as follows:

> >gene_44|105_nt|+|47540|47644
>   GTGCGCCGGCGCGTCGCGATCGCGAACCGGCCCGTGCGAATCCTGCCGCATGCGCGCCGCATCTCGCCACGCCGCGCATTTCATTTCGACATCCATAACGTCTGA
>
> >gene_88|177_nt|-|97993|98169
>   ATGCGCCAGCCGACGCACGCCCATTCCGGGCGAAACGTTCCCCTTATCCATTCGATCATCCGTGCCGCACTGCGCGAAGCGGCCACCGCCGACACGTACCAAACCGCGCTCGATGCGACCGGCGCGGCACTCGTCGCCATCGCGGCGCTCGTGCGCGCGGAGGTGCGGCATGGCTGA

How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

next time when you ask question, please show your code, for example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @genes;

open my $list, '<file2.list';
while (my $line = <$list>) {
    push (@genes, $1) if $line =~ /[^>]+>([^|]+)/;

}
my $input;
close $list;
{
    local $/ = undef;
    open my $fasta, '<file1.fasta';
    $input = <$fasta>;
    close $fasta;
}
my @lines = split(/>/,$input);
foreach my $l (@lines) {
    foreach my $reg (@genes) {
        print ">$l" if $l =~ /$reg/
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Suic. This seems work partly for me, but I've got some problem. Let's say if there was another sequence with header ">gene_449|141_nt|-|99016|99156" in file1.fasta, this sequence will also include in the output file which in fact it shouldn't. This might because of the string 'gene_44' in file2.list match with it, so this sequence also include in the output. How can I get rid of that? Thanks once again.

Comment: you can fix it, by change this line `print ">$l" if $l =~ /$reg\|/;`

Comment: @Suic- It's really works for me! I've been tried for whole day just to solve this problem >.< A thousand thanks!! :)